# Copy results of a query function from one worksheet and append it at the end of another worksheet in a diferent file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, macro-recorder

Is it possible to select the results of a QUERY (`=query(Dom,"select * WHERE G is not null")`) function from google sheet and append it at the end of another google sheet?

> Error: "Cannot find method openById(string,string).

I basically have two Google Sheets in two different locations and they both are in a flat-file format.

```
function Dom() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Dom_Sum').showSheet()
  .activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Dom_Sum'), true);
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  
  
 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("17J0_YiUANs9CZNmq2tqqvwjdAT2P8IVcx3NYljhqTFk","Master_Db!A1");
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
 sheet.copyTo(destination);
  
 
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Dom_Sum').hideSheet()
    
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Indent Form_Dom').showSheet()
  .activate();
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(['C4:D9', 'A12:M112']).activate()
  .clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('C4').activate();

  
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing two parameters to [openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) when it only admits one.

Also, if I understand you correctly, you just want to copy the (non null) data from column G to another sheet.

If that is so, you can try this:

```
function Dom() {
  var origin_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dom_Sum');
  var firstRow = 1;
  var firstCol = 7;
  var numRows = origin_sheet.getLastRow();
  var numCols = 1;
  var origin_values = origin_sheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();
  var dest_values = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < origin_values.length; i++) {
    if(origin_values[i][0] != '') {
      dest_values.push(origin_values[i]);
    }
  }
  var dest_id = "1ZGq7L7bvF1INuDgZxhHnVsihkYkYubmncSAE5uC-Pq4";
  var dest_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dest_id).getSheetByName("Master_Db");
  var numRowsDest = dest_values.length;
  var dest_range = dest_sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRowsDest, 1);
  dest_range.setValues(dest_values);
}
```

If this is not what you wanted I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi OMila, I can't thank you enough for taking a look at my issue. Your approach feels absolutely correct, however, I am only getting data of column G in the dest_sheet. Also, I would like the new rows of data to be added below, currently its overwriting previous data. I believe its something silly that I am missing.  Could we connect, please? boseav@gmail.com

Comment: I just need the rows (without the headers) to append below the existing data if any. Please help me @OMila, I can't take the anxiety any more!